# Spring Security mapping uppercase in URL

Tags: spring, url, spring-boot, spring-security

I work on a JEE project, using the Spring Boot framework.
For the authentification, I use Spring Security, and I specified the pages in my template.

```java
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/token", "/index", "/index.html", "/main", "/main.html", "/main2", "/main2.html", "/recent1", "/recent1.html", "/recent2", "/recent2.html").hasRole("USER");

    http
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index");

    http
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
}
```

The issue is that when I run the application and I wrote the URL with uppercase letters like: `localhost:8080/INDEX.HTML` or I add two letters `localhost/index.httml`, the page does appear without authantification.

Comment: you can this solution .antMatchers("/login","/LOGIN"). and the other like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, here is the desired logic:

1. `/login` does not need to be secured by Spring Security (no roles are required)
2. All the other pages have to be secured with "USER" role.

To implement this, you could try the following:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    // configuring here URLs for which security filters
    // will be disabled (this is equivalent to using
    // security="none")
    web
        .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/login"
            )
    ;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER");

    http.csrf().disable().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index");

    http.logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
}
```

So item 1 (no security on `/login`) is moved to `configure(WebSecurity)`, and item 2 is left in the original `configure(HttpSecurity)`.

Comment: thanks for your reply , yes all the page are secured , the problem is that when i put /INDEX (with uppercase letters ), the login does not appear , it call directly index without authentification!

Comment: In your configuration you list all your pages (including `/index`, `/index.html`) and set the security attributes for them. But you don't set any attributes for a 'all the others' case. `INDEX.HTML` and `index.httml` do not match the `/index` matcher, so NO security is applied for them. `anyRequest()` configuration in my answer instructs Spring Security to require authentication on **all URLs** (but /login).